# Notification -- Strings are not fully visible

Tags: java, android, notifications

[looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MuTk.png)

[image]

In the picture , the place of red rect ,Strings are not fully visible...

Character too many incomplete display can be made into the font scroll?

Can the string to display with Marquee effect ?

Comment: how you are setting notification ? show some code

Comment: you can set style to notification using **setStyle** method like this **.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().setSummaryText(message);**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add scrolling. Depending on the version you're targeting, [multi line notifications](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html) may work.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the scrolling is not possible. But you can use expandable notification view. 
[Notification Expanded](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html)